# Which part of mvc design pattern represents the business logic?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, business-logic

I am a little confused about the definition of the **business logic** in programming because I used to develop without paying an attention to any of these terminologies but now I want to be a good developer.

While I was reading in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic) about the definition of the business logic I have read the following definition:

> In computer software, business logic or domain logic is the part of the program that encodes the real-world business rules that determine how data can be created, displayed, stored, and changed.

and in another [website](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?BusinessLogicDefinition) I have read the following definition with example:

> Business logic is that portion of an enterprise system which determines how data is:
>   Transformed and/or calculated. For example, business logic determines how a tax total is calculated from invoice line items.
>   Routed to people or software systems, aka workflow.

So I am wondering about which part of the MVC represents the business logic, is it the controller or the model or another part could be in the MVC?

I know that the controller is responsible for sending commands to the model but is it responsible for applying the rules of the business?

For example let's take the above example of the tax:

Suppose that we got the invoice data from a form in a view, the data will be directed to the controller but where the tax will be calculated, will we calculate it in the controller or will we ask for the help of an external class to compute it or will we compute it in the model before updating the database?

Could Example would be appreciated.

Comment: the Model should be where business logic is made

Comment: in the strictest sense, none of the above.  Asp.Net MVC is a presentation framework.  The **M**odel is the Business Data that you want to display, the **V**iew is the way the data is displayed, and the **C**ontroller handles the interactions between the View, the Model, and Business logic in other tiers of the application.  You *could* do all your business logic in the Controller (or the Model) if your application is small enough, but in many cases, it's not handled in any of these 3 tiers.

Comment: @Claies, suppose the we apply the business rule in a different tier else the Model, in this case the Model will serve as a data access layer to add, delete and update the data, but  in case that we use EFW why should we use the model in this case?

Comment: the point I was trying to make is that most applications are more than 3 tiers, and enterprise applications may have business tiers that interact with MVC for web views, WPF for desktop views, etc., and to assume that business logic must reside in one of the 3 tiers only is completely false.

Comment: Don't assume that _model_ is a single layer. It is common to have _view models_ that represent the data required for each view and _data models_ that represent the underlying business/domain data in the same application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* put the tax calculation logic in the Controller, but you're better off putting it in the Model as it is more loosely coupled. It is reasonable to want to calculate tax on lots of pages, so don't put it in lots of controllers, put it in a model that can be re-used.

If you hear someone talking about "Fat" Controllers vs "Thin" Controllers, that is what they're talking about. Most devs will advocate having very little code in their controllers (making them "thin") and really just acting as a relay/orchestrator off to the Model.

I do think the term `Model` is a bit confusing though because in Service Oriented Architecture (and functional languages for that matter), they stress trying to have "dumb" objects that don't have any functionality and they frequently refer those dumb objects as "Models". But when it comes to MVC, the "Model" really refers to the Business Model, which incorporates dumb objects that hold values AND the services that work on top of them.

Comment: this is a great answer but @Claies answered a different answer in a comment so what do you think about that comment?

Comment: Yeah, I think we're mostly on the same page. The problem is really in the naming collision with the name "Model". Unfortunately it is just kind of wishy washy. It started out as one thing, perhaps got differently interpreted and is now kind of a soup. I think most people would agree, as long as you're keeping your controllers thin, the stratification or tiering of the Model is orthogonal to the original question.

Comment: I thought about this some more... please don't spend too much time worrying about the "what" or "how", the most important part is the "why". Regardless of how you (or the articles you read) decide to name things, the important thing is that you have a clear separation of concerns so that you can make changes more easily. That is the driving force, adaptiveness to change.

Answer (score 0):

In Enterprise software development, must of time we use N-tier applications. They are 3 or more tiers.
1- Data tier:
2- Application tier (**business logic**, logic tier, or middle tier) 
3- Presentation tier: it is a layer which users can access directly such as a web page, including simple control and user input validation or an operating systems **GUI**. , .

MVC is one of the seminal insights in the early development of **graphical user interfaces**, and one of the first approaches to describe and implement software constructs in terms of their responsibilities
This said that MVC is use as a presentation layer. They are others like MVP, MVVM..
Sometime time in small application, an MVC structure is use to separate layer where the model is use as data layer, the controller as Logic layer.